# UINavigationBAr Title as an Image, used to work, doesn't display anymore in XCode9

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'm having a small annoying issue, I'm using storyboards on this app since it's creation, I want to make an update to it and something that used to work before doesn't anymore

See I was using an image as a UINavigationBar Title, Dragged it to the storyboard and it worked almost automatically,

Now well the image doesn't display anymore... Here's a screen :

[image]

As you Can see, the UIImageView is there, but nothing shows up. and when I run the app, still nothing...

I'd like to solve it trought Storyboards, but my knowledge is limited

thanks

Comment: check the image name

Comment: what's wrong with it? it references the right png